# Magento 1.9xx - Not valid template file

Tags: magento-1.9, template

Today I took a look into the system.log from one of our Magento shops and I saw that there is an error:

> 2019-01-20T09:05:52+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/mini.phtml

Does anyone know where I have to look to change the path where it's looking for? The file doesn't exists on the server so the file that is asking for mini.phtml needs te be located, but how can I know which file is asking for mini.phtml?

Thanks!

**More info**

I see this in the system.log every time when an order is placed:

> 2019-01-25T08:51:18+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from `MacRoman' to`UTF-16BE' is not allowed  in /home/website/domains/websitename.nl/public_html/lib/Zend/Pdf/FileParser.php on line 451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you set a **wrong** template path, **Magento** Check that file in your `current theme`, then `default`, then the `base` one what is called **Magento fallback system**.

So check this in the **xml** files, start with this one:

> app/design/frontend/{package}/{current-theme}/layout/local.xml

Comment: Exactly! That's indeed the correct place, thanks! :)

Comment: You're welcome, good luck

Answer (score 2):

By taking help of your code editor (like **sublime text**/ **netbeans**/ **PHPStorm** etc.), you can search for the file name **mini.phtml**.

It will help you locate the file from where the file **mini.phtml** is being called.

Further, for the second problem,

> 2019-01-25T08:51:18+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: iconv(): Wrong charset,
>   conversion from MacRoman' toUTF-16BE' is not allowed in
>   /home/website/domains/websitename.nl/public_html/lib/Zend/Pdf/FileParser.php
>   on line 451

you can take help from:

- https://www.sonassi.com/blog/knowledge-base/magento-wrong-charset-conversion-from-utf-16be-to-utf-8-is-not-allowed